# ignoredWordsInSpellDocumentWithTag, what's the tag?

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

I suspect I'm missing something very obvious, but looking over the NSSpellChecker I'm stumped about what tag I should use in ignoredWordsInSpellDocumentWithTag *et al*.

My goal is to save and load these from files external to the document itself (the document is a bare text file). But the documentation is very sparse on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I never haves worked with the spell checker, but the [documentation for spell checking](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/Tasks/CheckingTextSpelling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000721-98120-CJBFIHIG) says that it is a unique identifier that helps the spell checker to match a string to a ignored words list. You can get a tag with `+uniqueSpellDocumentTag` and use it for setting the ignored words list.

Comment: Wow, didn't even see that.  So it appears that this is saved into the "master dictionary"?